# edit date saved in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would appreciate help. I have a select date which records the date perfectly, the issue is that I want to press the modify button to bring me the previously saved date.

Is there any way to perform this task?

This is my code:

```
<p><label>Fecha:</label> <p type="Fecha:"><input type="date" name="fecha" step="1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" autocomplete="off" required value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" /><?php echo form_error("fecha", "<span class='help-block'>", "</span>") ?> </p></p>
```

Comment: Where is the "modify" button?

Comment: what you are asking ? i can't understand